Is a movie resonsible for damages caused to unintentional (but undeniable) likenesses?
Say that a huge blockbuster movie mentions a made-up phone number (xxx) xxx-xxxx for the serial killer villain. Except, it turns out that that phone number is real and points to an ordinary Joe. That ordinary Joe is now constantly bombarded with calls. Does ordinary Joe have a case against the people behind the huge blockbuster movie?
Similarly, if a blockbuster movie makes a doctor named "Xavier Young" who turns out to be a serial killer, and there's an actual doctor named "Xavier Young" who loses business over this, can Xavier Young take action against the movie makers?
This isn't exactly related (since I'm pretty sure they made a deal with the show), but the real owners of Walter White's house from Breaking Bad have constantly had pizzas thrown on their roof (because it was something that happened in the show) as well as people stopping and taking pictures of their house all the time.
On one hand, I'd think this is protected under free speech. On the other hand, movies often start with a "all likenesses are a coincidence" disclaimer, which means the moviemakers have something to be afraid of. Are moviemakers in trouble if they don't post that disclaimer, and are they off-the-hook if they do post that disclaimer? Personally, it seems to me that such a disclaimer would be as powerful as posting "I do not give permission for anyone to access my data" on Facebook (i.e. useless). In any case, I'm not sure where the law might fall in this case.

there used to be a phone number block that would not be used for exactly that reason. 555-01xx is a common one, because that block is explicitly reserved to not be given out. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_telephone_number

@Trish not always... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny

@Trish None of the references to the 555 block for movies properly explain why 555 was chosen. Back in the day, the number to call on the Bell System for "Information" aka directory assistance was 555-1212, but any other random four digits like 555-9876 also went direct to "Information". I'm old enough to have tried it when an actual human operator would answer with the word "Informaysheeun" and you could have a dialog to find a phone number at no charge. So no matter what number you dialed after 555-, you would get directory assistance, not a person's private number. Perfect for movies,

Funny story: The German band "Spider Murphy Gang" had a funny smash hit "Skandal im Sperrbezirk" featuring  a prostitute in Munich with the number 32-16-8.  They had cleared the number in Munich but it was in use in some other cities. Off course prank and idiot calls came along. The band paid for number changes and sent quite a few "apology" flowers around to settle it up.  That was a while ago and Germany isn't nearly as litigious as the US, so that was the end of it and everyone seemed more amused than offended.
